# μtorrent - Display "Downloaded" in MB rather than GB?

Tags: bittorrent, utorrent

Is there a way to display the amount downloaded in MB? For example, when a download is at 1.3 GB, show 1331 MB instead?

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RczUS.jpg)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible.

I remember one user claimed to have successfully changed the ***display of downloading speed*** from *bytes/sec to *bits/sec by using version 3.3, but one of the admins denied that there was any option like that.

[source](https://forum.utorrent.com/topic/80487-change-megabyte-megabit/)

> No version of uTorrent displays ANYTHING outside of the setup guide in *bit/sec.
>
> None of them.
>
> Not 2.2.1, not 3.3, not even 1.0
>
> They ALL display in *byte/sec.
>
> If you're using an old version because you think it displays in *bit/sec, you're using an old version because of an misguided reason.